# users_signup_test.rb fails at assert users.reload.activated. Expected false to be truthy. Railstutorial Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I follow the book railstutorial of micheal hartl. at chapter 11 my test fails in users_signup_test.rb. in my account_activations_contrller.rb file, the action edit, user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id]) is always false

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was me forgetting to refactor the authenticated? method properly

I had:

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  return false if remember_digest.nil?

  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

Notice the `remember_digest.nil?`

It should be:

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  debugger
  return false if digest.nil?

  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

Hope this helps